# How do you write unit tests with Parse in Xcode (Swift in my case)?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, parse-platform

This is my query. It's inside of the Tests target. And I set the applicationID and clientKey inside of AppDelegate.swift.

I put a breakpoint in AppDelegate.swift, so that is definitely getting hit when I run the test. It also hit the breakpoint I set before line 5 of the code below (customer.saveinbackgroundWithBlock...). But when I put a breakpoint right after that line, it wouldn't hit it, and the test would "succeed." Also, the Parse Dashboard shows that no customer was added.

I tested the same query in the normal app target, and that worked. Just not in test target.

```
func testCustomersExistCase() {
    // Save a test customer
    let customer = Customer(firstName: "Jonathan", lastName: "Goldsmith", email: "theMostInterestingManInTheWorld@en.wikipedia.org", streetAddress: "100 Main St", city: "Monterrey", state: "Texas", zipCode: "55555")
    customer.shopID = "dosequis"

    customer.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if success {
                print("This test should work.")
                self.customerSearchViewControllerDataSource.getAllCustomers(self.customeSearchViewController)

                // Check if it's in the customers array
                for customerResult in self.customeSearchViewController.data! {
                    if customerResult.objectId == customer.objectId {
                        XCTAssertTrue(true, "Success! Customer was added.")

                        // Delete customer if test had succeeded.
                        customer.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock({
                            (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                            if success {
                                print("Clean-up after test was successful")
                            } else {
                                print("Need to delete customer manually")
                            }
                        })
                    } else {
                        XCTAssertTrue(false, "Query is broken. Customer was not retrieved")
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print("This test will not work. Customer was not added to Parse")
            }
        if error != nil {
            print("This test isn't working. Parse threw an error.")
        }
    })
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the parse block executes on a different thread than your test runs on and so your test finishes unaware of what the parse block does.

To test async operations you should create an expectation in your XCTest subclass and call the waitForExpectation method. Here's a quick example:

View Controller w/method

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func getUserStuff(completionHandler: (succeeded: Bool) -> ()) {

}
}
```

The test:

```
func testGetUserInfo() {

    let vc = ViewController()

    let userOpExpectation: XCTestExpectation = expectationWithDescription("Got user info")

    vc.getUserStuff { (succeeded) in
        XCTAssert(succeeded, "Should get user stuff")
        userOpExpectation.fulfill()
    }

    waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(5.0, handler: nil)
}
```

There's a lot that goes into testing and Apple provides a lot, both in the way of included code and documentation, check out: https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/04-writing_tests.html for more info.

Comment: Thank you! I did see expectations in my research, but it never clicked that I would need them.

Comment: @ArthurAyetiss You're welcome! You'll get in a flow with them I'm sure. :)

Comment: What is supposed to be in the "getUserStuff" function?